# regarding image processing

Tags: java, image-processing

Can someone suggest a source code in java for obtaining pixel value of a gray scale image?

Comment: It depends completely on the format of your image and how it is represented in your program. We're going to need more details

Comment: was any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Old, but I guess still valid, http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html

Answer (score 0):

If your image comes from something biologically-related, then the [bioformats](http://www.loci.wisc.edu/software/bio-formats) library will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

For example by accessing it via the BufferedImage class

```
File f = new File("c:\images\myimage.gif");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(f);
```

You can then access the image data via

```
bufferedImage.getData()
```

- [BufferedImage javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)